# Drop constraint with special character in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to drop a constraint, but it has a special character in its name.

This is the problem:

```
ALTER TABLE USER_AEROPORTS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ACC_V_MOA-USU_AEROP;
```

This fails with

```
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

I believe it is the `-` in the constraint name.

How can I drop the constraint? I want to drop the constraint, not the column.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE USER_AEROPORTS DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_ACC_V_MOA-USU_AEROP";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can double-quote the constraint name:

```
ALTER TABLE USER_AEROPORTS DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_ACC_V_MOA-USU_AEROP";
```